# NuGet Issue after upgrade of teamcity (JetBrain)

Tags: nuget, teamcity

TeamCity Version: 2023.11

Steps to reproduce the problem:

Teamcity Configuration which is work with older version. but not it is not working.

I have setup of multiple project, which all package is refere to Nuget, but once of them is refere to Telerik ( telerik.report)

in step one we have nuget package Restoring NuGet where got error

NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

The expected result: build should complet

The actual result: not throwing error   NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

Comment: I will follow your [issue TW-85674](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-85674)